# Javascript forEach() through an array: how to get the previous and next item?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach

Let's say we have an array of objects like:

```
var fruits = [ {name:"banana", weight:150},{name:"apple", weight:130},{name:"orange", weight:160},{name:"kiwi", weight:80} ]
```

I want to iterate through fruits and tell each time the name of the current, the previous and the next fruit.
I would do something like:

```
fruits.forEach(function(item,index) {
console.log("Current: " + item.name);
console.log("Previous: " + item[index-1].name);  
console.log("Next: " + item[index-1].name);
});
```

But obviously it doesn't work for next and previous items...
Any idea?

Please note that I do not want to use the classic for loop

> (for i=0; i

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `fruits[index-1]`...

Comment: Shouldn't you use `fruits[index-1]`?

Comment: 'item' holds only current object in forEach method. If you know any index, then use array[index] to get the value.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Its not working because item is not an array so we cannot write item[index-1].name. Instead, we need to use fruits[index-1] .Also, the first element of the array will not have the previous item and the last element will not have next item.
Code snippet below should work for you.

```
var fruits = [{
    name: "banana",
    weight: 150
}, {
    name: "apple",
    weight: 130
}, {
    name: "orange",
    weight: 160
}, {
    name: "kiwi",
    weight: 80
}]

fruits.forEach(function(item, index) {
    console.log("Current: " + item.name);
    if (index > 0) {
        console.log("Previous: " + fruits[index - 1].name);
    }
    if (index < fruits.length - 1) {
        console.log("Next: " + fruits[index + 1].name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Callback function in ForEach loop accepts the array as third parameter :

```
fruits.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
    console.log("Current: " + item.name);
    console.log("Previous: " + ((0 === index)? "START" : arr[index-1].name));
    console.log("Next: " + ((arr.length - 1 === index)? "END" : arr[index+1].name));
});
```

Answer (score 6):

For the first and last item, you can log END, or you can make it a carousel.

**option 1**: mark the start and the end:

```
fruits.forEach(function(item,index) {
  console.log("Current: " + item.name);
  console.log("Previous: " + (0 == index)? "START" : fruits[index-1].name);  
  console.log("Next: " + (fruits.length - 1 == index)? "END" : fruits[index+1].name);
});
```

**option 2**: carousel

```
fruits.forEach(function(item,index) {
      console.log("Current: " + item.name);
      console.log("Previous: " + (0 == index)? fruits[fruits.length - 1].name : fruits[index-1].name);  
      console.log("Next: " + (fruits.length - 1 == index)? fruits[0].name : fruits[index+1].name);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
fruits.forEach(function(item,index) {
  console.log("Current: " + item.name);
  if (index > 0) {
    console.log("Previous: " + fruits[index-1].name);  
  }
  if (index < (fruits.length - 1)) {
    console.log("Next: " + fruits[index+1].name);
  }
});
```

Comment: would fail for 0th index and sparse array values :)

Comment: @you.know.nothing Thanks for pointing it out. Didn't think of it.