# handlebars, access to parent each loop variable

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I have code like here. I would like to set input name to @index from previous each loop.

Can I access @previousIndex somehow? Or can I assign inputs to some kind of group created before second each loop that will set all input names inside?

Data I receive:

```
 questions:[  
  {  
     question:"How old are you?",
     answers:[  
        '16',
        '18',
        '20',
        '25',
        'other'
     ]
  },
  {  
     question:"How many kids do you have?",
     answers:[  
        '0',
        '1',
        '2',
        'other'
     ]
  }
]
```

hbs code:

```
{{#each questions}}
    <li>
        <h3 class='question'>{{this.question}}</h2>
        <div class='flexbox'>
            {{#each this.answers}}
            <label class="container">
                <input type='radio' name='{{@previousIndex}}' value='{{@index}}'>  
                <span class='checkmark'>{{this}}</span>
            </label>              
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696860/javascript-foreach-through-an-array-how-to-get-the-previous-and-next-item

Comment: Is this solved? check the answer below? Did it work?

Comment: I post my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using #each then you get the index in `@index` and if you want previousIndex why not just do `parseInt(@index) - 1`

Here's how you do it:

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

Handlebars.registerHelper("previous", function(value, options)
{
    return parseInt(value) - 1;
});
```

Now update your hbs code as:

```
{{#each questions}}
    <li>
        <h3 class='question'>{{this.question}}</h2>
        <div class='flexbox'>
            {{#each this.answers}}
            <label class="container">
                <input type='radio' name='{{previous @index}}' value='{{@index}}'>  
                <span class='checkmark'>{{this}}</span>
            </label>              
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a 100% working code (environment is not currently setup) but from my previous experience with handlebars I will try to guide you to a possible solution.

```
{{assign "previousIndex" 0}}
{{#each questions}}
    <li>
        <h3 class='question'>{{this.question}}</h2>
        <div class='flexbox'>
            {{#each this.answers}}
            <label class="container">
                <input type='radio' name='{{../previousIndex}}' value='{{@index}}'>  
                <span class='checkmark'>{{this}}</span>
            </label>              
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </li>
    {{assign "../previousIndex" "{{@index}}"}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to create two helper functions like here. Get is here because I wasn`t able to access variable directly from .hbs file by simply writing {{myVariableName}}.
Hbs file looks now like here.

```
<div class='flexbox'>
            {{assign "parentIndex" @index }}
            {{#each this.answers}}
            <label class="container">
                <input type='radio' name='{{get "parentIndex"}}' value='{{@index}}'>  
                <span class='checkmark'>{{this}}</span>
            </label>              
            {{/each}}
        </div>
```

helpers

```
assign: function(varName, varValue, options) {
    options.data.root[varName] = varValue;
}

get: function(varName, options) {
    return options.data.root[varName]
}
```