# How get prev data in foreach reactnative

Tags: react-native, foreach

I decide to get distance between locations in react native with geolib
but I don't how to get previous or next location in foreach 
my code

```
  Array.from(locations).forEach(item=>{
      if(geolib.getDistance({latitude : item.latitude ,longitude: item.longitude},{latitude:35.75,longitude:51.456})/1000 > 200 ){
        console.log('longer than 200m')
      }else {
        console.log('bala bala ')
      }

      })
```

My problem is how to get previous data in foreach

Solve it !!
[Javascript forEach() through an array: how to get the previous and next item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696860/javascript-foreach-through-an-array-how-to-get-the-previous-and-next-item)