# How to target specific index with forEach array method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So what I want to do is console.log a specific element of my array of three nodes.

```
const sentinel = document.querySelectorAll('.sentinel');

    sentinel.forEach(function(element, index){
    setInterval(function(element) {

        if(index === 0){
            console.log(element);
        }

    }, 3000);
});
```

I've googled, and I've found this post: [Get a specific element within forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57231827/get-a-specific-element-within-foreach-loo), which does ask the same question. However, when I console log the element I expect to get the node on the 0 index. However, I get a null element.

Comment: Remove the `element` parameter from the `setInterval` callback

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). There it is mentioned how you can pass something to the callback invoked by `setInterval()` (which in this case is not necessary because it's in a `.forEach()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove `element` from `setInterval` because inner function `setInterval` has an access to the variables of outer function such as `element`. Such behavior is called  closure.

In addition, it is possible to use arrow functions to make shorter and cleaner your code. Moreover, [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the
>   enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
>   variable lookup rules.

```
sentinel.forEach((element, index) => {
   setInterval(() =>{

    if (index === 0){
        console.log(element);
    }

}, 3000);
```

Comment: The callback can get arguments. It needs to be passed after the delay parameter to `setInterval`

Comment: What do arrow functions have to do with the problem/answer?

Comment: _"You can remove `element` from `setInterval`"_ - Why?

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the problem.

Also thanks for the heads up with arrow functions. Might be a cleaner way to do it!

Comment: Better but I still miss an explanation why just using `element` works. But why the quote on `this` for arrow functions? Neither you nor OP use `this` anywhere. And if you're already adding unrelated stuff then also add a link to the question why you can not always simply exchange a `function() { ... }` with an arrow function.

Comment: @Andreas 1.*I still miss an explanation why just using element works* Because inner function `setInterval` has an access to the variables of outer function such as `element`. Such behavior is called  closure 2. *But why the quote on this for arrow functions?* This quote is additional info to describe important feature of arrow functions

Answer (score 1):

So actually you need to bind element into **setInterval** function

```
const sentinel = document.querySelectorAll('.sentinel');

sentinel.forEach(function(element, index){
    (function (_element, _index){
        setInterval(function() {

           if(_index === 0){
             console.log(_element);
           }

        }, 3000);
    })(element, index);
});
```

Comment: There is no need for IIFE here. You can pass arguments to the callback from `setInterval` itself. Anything passed after 3000 (delay parameter), will be used in the callback. So, `setInterval(function (e, i) {... }, 3000, element, index)` should work. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Example_1_Basic_syntax)